# Making write buffer available for flushing by another thread

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, pthreads, mutex

I have a scenario where I want to write data behind an API call to disk. Performance is critical so I write data per thread to separate per-thread files. To optimize the write, I buffer data in memory and write the buffer when the buffer is full or the data in the buffer is aged.

The problem is I can't have the data in the buffer aged too much. I can only write the data when the API function is called. If the API function is called once and I buffer the data, I then have to wait until the API function is called again to determine if the data is stale or buffer is full, to write it to disk. That might be too late and the data is too stale.

I was thinking I could have another thread which periodically checks the buffer, and writes the data out anyway if it's aged too much. I'd like to do in a performant way, not using pthread conditions and mutexes, but (ideally) atomics and the like, which I believe to be faster. I'm not sure about the GCC builtins required to make this work. Most documentation around memory fences seems to do with instruction ordering, not visibility.

Comment: What is your question?  You might be asking "is it sensible to try using atomics, etc", or "how do I do it using atomics, etc" or something else.  Have you measured the performance of using conditions and mutexes?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to do in a performant way, not using pthread conditions and mutexes, but (ideally) atomics and the like, which I believe to be faster.

Your belief is incorrect. Atomics and the like have no ability to deschedule a thread when there's contention. Mutexes and conditions do. There will be no payoff, and possibly a slight performance cost, to doing this with more complexity than needed.